# Form not found or not recognized

Tags: python, django

I have `ModelMultipleChoiceField` form in my `form.py` like this :

```
class UserResponseSearchForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qry = kwargs.pop('qry')
        super(UserResponseSearchForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['gejala_id0'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.filter(gejala__icontains=qry).values_list('gejala', flat=True).distinct().order_by('gejala'),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)

    gejala_id1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.all().values_list('gejala', flat=True).distinct().filter(id_organ=1).order_by('gejala'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
    gejala_id2 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.all().values_list('gejala', flat=True).distinct().filter(id_organ=2).order_by('gejala'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
    gejala_id3 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.all().values_list('gejala', flat=True).distinct().filter(id_organ=3).order_by('gejala'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
```

And my views.py like this :

```
def responsePenyakit(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserResponseForm(request.POST)
        gejala0 = form["gejala_id0"].data
        gejala1 = form["gejala_id1"].data
        gejala2 = form["gejala_id2"].data
        gejala3 = form["gejala_id3"].data

        if (len(gejala0) > 0):
            for i in range(0, len(gejala0)):
                userAnswer = UserAnswer()
                userAnswer.gejala_answer = gejala1[i]
                userAnswer.user_id = request.user.id
                userAnswer.number_diagnosis = user.number_diagnosis + 1
                userAnswer.save()
                print(gejala0)

        if (len(gejala1) > 0):
            for i in range(0, len(gejala1)):
                userAnswer = UserAnswer()
                userAnswer.gejala_answer = gejala1[i]
                userAnswer.user_id = request.user.id
                userAnswer.number_diagnosis = user.number_diagnosis + 1
                userAnswer.save()

        if (len(gejala2) > 0):
            for i in range(0, len(gejala2)):
                userAnswer = UserAnswer()
                userAnswer.gejala_answer = gejala2[i]
                userAnswer.user_id = request.user.id
                userAnswer.number_diagnosis = user.number_diagnosis + 1
                userAnswer.save()

        if (len(gejala3) > 0):
            for i in range(0, len(gejala3)):
                userAnswer = UserAnswer()
                userAnswer.gejala_answer = gejala3[i]
                userAnswer.user_id = request.user.id
                userAnswer.number_diagnosis = user.number_diagnosis + 1
                userAnswer.save()
    return redirect('diagnosis_penyakit:response_matching')
else:
    raise Http404
```

I want to get the data what i choose from `gejala_id0` form. I try to get the data like what i do in my `views.py`.

But there is return error `Key 'gejala_id0' not found in 'UserResponseForm'.` What's the problem in there? I think what i do is correct. CMIIW

Please help me. I am new in django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create field first and then change queryset in `__init__`.

```
class UserResponseSearchForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qry = kwargs.pop('qry')
        super(UserResponseSearchForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['gejala_id0'].queryset = Gejala.objects.filter(gejala__icontains=qry).values_list('gejala', flat=True).distinct().order_by('gejala')

    gejala_id0 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
    gejala_id1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.all().values_list('gejala', flat=True).distinct().filter(id_organ=1).order_by('gejala'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
    gejala_id2 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.all().values_list('gejala', flat=True).distinct().filter(id_organ=2).order_by('gejala'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
    gejala_id3 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.all().values_list('gejala', flat=True).distinct().filter(id_organ=3).order_by('gejala'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
```

also send qry to form:

```
def responsePenyakit(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserResponseForm(data=request.POST, qry=query)
```

Comment: Error `NameError: name 'qry' is not defined`

Comment: you use qry in `UserResponseSearchForm.__init__`. what is it ?

Comment: to get string what i input in searchbar

Comment: but you didn't pass qry to form. so `qry = kwargs.pop('qry')` always be `None`.

Comment: tell me where you get `qry`.

Comment: so how do i pass `qry` to form?

Comment: `form = UserResponseForm(data=request.POST, qry=qry)`.

Comment: i just do like that but there is same error like in first comment

Comment: how you pass `qry` in to searchbar ?

Comment: `def search(request):
    template = 'penyakit/home.html'

    query = request.GET.get('q')
                                                                                       gejala__icontains=query).order_by( 'gejala')


    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        form_review = ReviewUserForm(request.POST or None)
        form = UserResponseSearchForm(request.POST or None, qry=query)`

Comment: New error mate after i follow with your code there is error `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'` in `gejala_id0`

Comment: try this => `UserResponseSearchForm(data=request.POST or None, qry=query)`

Comment: Same error mate missing `queryset` to make a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`

Comment: try this => ` gejala_id0 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)`

Comment: New error mate `Key 'gejala_id0' not found in 'UserResponseForm'` in `gejala0 = form["gejala_id0"].data`

Comment: first of all check the `form.is_valid()` and then for access the field value use `form.cleaned_data['gejala_id0']`.